# Firebase Cloud Functions work locally, but not remotely

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

No log errors locally or remotely. Function executes fine on my machine. Remotely, it executes, and I get a 200 return, but it never actually updates anything in my Firestore db. The Function successfully reaches out to Shopify's API to pull product details, and it gives a response message that "x products have been processed", which is accurate, but just before that 200 response is sent back to the browser, it is supposed to run an update against the Firestore db for each of those "x" products. Nothing is being created in Firestore. Anything you can think to check?

Comment: Please help us out by showing the code that's not working the way we expect.  Without that, there's no way to tell what you might be doing wrong.